# Uncaught Exception when programmatically appending a script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programmatically appending a script to the DOM because I have to dynamically create the URL from a config file.  When I execute the code, I get a "uncaught Exception: Object" in the Firefox web console.  This happens in the last line of init.js: `document.head.appendChild(scriptElement)`.  However, the script does get added successfully and I am able to successfully access the Google Maps API.

js/init.js:

```
console.log('importing')
import config from "./config.js";

import {callGoogle, handleError} from "./api.js";

const init = () => {
    console.log('init')
    console.log('apiKey', config.google.apiKey)

    window.onerror = function (msg, url, line) {
        const err = `Uncaught Exception: ${msg} ${url} ${line}`;
        // handleError(err);
    }


    const handleSubmit = function (caller) {
        console.log('handleSubmit', window, caller)
        try {
            const address = caller.form.elements.address.value;
            const phone = caller.form.elements.phone.value;
            const fileElement = document.getElementById('file') //caller.form.elements.file.baseURI;
            const file = fileElement && fileElement.files && fileElement.files[0]

            console.log('handleSubmit', 'address', address, 'phone', phone, 'file', file);

            if (!address && !phone && !file) {
                throw new Error('Address, phone number, or file must be provided')
            }

            if ((address && phone) || (address && file) || (phone && file)) {
                return handleError(new Error('You can only enter in an address or a phone number or a file'))
            }

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (e) => {
                    console.log('!!!!! onload', e)
                    var fileContents = e.target.result;
                    callGoogle(config.google.apiKey, address, phone, fileContents)
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);

            } else {
                callGoogle(config.google.apiKey, address, phone, null)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            handleError(err)
        }
    }

    window.onload = () => {
        try {
            console.log('onload');
            var button = document.getElementById('submit');
            button.addEventListener('click', function () {
                console.log('adding button event listener');
                handleSubmit(this);
            });


        } catch (err) {
            handleError(err)
        }
    };

    var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
    scriptElement.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + config.google.apiKey + "&libraries=places&callback=initMap";
    scriptElement.defer = true;
    console.log('document', document);
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);

};

export {
    init,
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Google Maps Places to CSV</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">-->

    <style>
        .message {
            color: red;
            font-size: 150%;
        }

        input, textarea, select, submit {
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0;

            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy WebKit based browsers */
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* For legacy (Firefox <29) Gecko based browsers */
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/google-libphonenumber@3.2.3/dist/libphonenumber.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<br/>
<h3>Google Maps Places: Get Business Name, Address, Phone Numbers, and Website by Searching by Addresses or Phone
    Number. Results are Exported to CSV
</h3>
<div class="message" id="message"></div>
<div id="form">
    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="address">Address:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
        </div>
        <br/>
        or
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <br/>
        or
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div>
            <label for="file">CSV File (Header in first row: 'address' first column, 'phone' in the second). Addresses
                and phone numbers don't need to match in the same row. Only the address or phone number is needed for
                each place searched:</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
        </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">-->
        <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="module">
    import {init} from './js/init.js';

    console.log('init1', init)
    init()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We would need more info about this, to be honest. The error is not very detailed and might not even be related to your code at all, but the code in the appended script. Theres no way for us to know.

Comment: @somethinghere, you're right. It looks like it had to do with the initMap callback in the Place Search Google Maps URL.  I'm not using that callback so just removing that got rid of the error.

Comment: Wahey! Good to hear it worked out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not using the initMap callback in the Place Search Google Maps URL, I just removed it from the query parameter to get rid of the error.